# website text not mobile friendly

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the problem that my text is not responsive, i tried to delete the text, the image is responsive, just the text is not..there is a **white border.**
i dont know how to fix that problem, it hink there is something with my css code, but i dont know what.

```css
#stage {
    background: url('../img/ozadje.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


#stage-caption{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#stage-caption h1{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color:silver;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 150%;
    
        
}
#stage-caption p{
   color:silver ;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

```html
      
      <div id="stage">
     <div id="stage-caption">
     <h1 class="display-3">
         THERE'S ONLY ONE MIHAEL SOBOČAN, WEB DESIGNER & PROGRAMMER!
     </h1></div>
      </div>
```

screenshot of the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBKyO.png

Comment: What white border? Please, read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue some other way, maybe a screenshot or drawing?

Comment: How is the text not responsive?

Comment: Your tags don't have any relevance either, this is not a good question :(

Comment: there is a screenshot of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest, it only starts happening once you get down to really small screen sizes.. so it may not be worth even worrying baout really.

BUt the problem is that the word 'PROGRAMMER' is too long to get any shorter, and pushes the width of the viewport out further.

So your solution, if you really are worried about it, is to reduce the font size with a media query under 768px.

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    #stage-caption h1 {font-size:1em;}
}
```

Comment: i put a screenshot there, please help me with that

Comment: But you need to explain it much more. What would you like it to look like, and can you re-create it using JSFiddle? Doe you have a viewport meta tag?

Comment: you see the white border from the end of the background img to the end of the screen. and the text obove it, the text should be over the image without the white border..that is not how a responsive website should look

Comment: Okay, no it's not.. but by the sounds of it you haven't tried to make your website responsive at all, so it's not going to look like it, is it? Have you got a viewport meta tag for a start? Can you give a link to your site please?

Comment: yes i have the meta tag. I made the site with bootstrap [link](http://www.mihaelsobocan.com)